# Same listview 2 different page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I want to use the same listview on two different pages how can I do. So I want to show the same listview on two different pages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Tobacco.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Tobacco.Views.NewItemPage"
             Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"
             Title="New Item">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#0c7b93</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Accent}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ContentView Padding="0,40,0,40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image Source="add_product.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="64" />
                </ContentView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,90,30,24" Spacing="7">
                <Entry Placeholder="Ürün Kodu" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtProductCode" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="Marka" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtProductBrand"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="Ürün" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtProductName"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="Fiyat" FontSize="16" x:Name="txtProductPrice"/>
                <Button Margin="0,15,0,0" Text="Ürün Ekle"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        TextColor="White" x:Name="addProduct" Clicked="addProduct_Clicked"/>
                <ContentView>
                    <ListView x:Name="lstProducts">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextCell Text="{Binding ProductName}" Detail="{Binding ProductPrice}"></TextCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ContentView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: either just copy and paste, or encapsulate your ListView in a ContentView and reference it on both pages

Comment: I couldn't solve it with copy and paste. Can you explain in a simpler way, I'm new yet.

Comment: if you want more help you need to post your code.  Please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: If you copy the XAML for the ListView to the XAML on a new page, what happens?  That is literally the simplest way possible to share code.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't happen either. Let me explain as follows: I have two xaml pages, one will register a product and the other will show these records in a listview. I hope it has become more understandable. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That doesn't sound like two pages with the same ListView.  That sounds like one page with a data entry form and another page with a ListView.

Comment: I changed my mind because I couldn't, I'm sorry

Comment: are not you going to help

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're doing or what problem you're facing.  You haven't answered the very simple question I asked you.  And the last comment you made was "I changed my mind" without providing any useful explanation of what that means.  I suggest you delete this question and post a new one that **clearly** explains the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't know how it happened but somehow I did it thank you for your help

Comment: So you have one xaml page that lists products, so that is one item source; so then you add them (i assume it is saved to some db or something). Second xaml page then just needs to copy the same code and have a different item source. That's all